# Find the complete integral $z=px + qy + pq$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> Find the complete integral of $z=px + qy +pq$, where  $p={ \partial  z \over \partial x},q={ \partial  z \over \partial y}$.

*My Attempt*:

The given equation is : $f(x,y,z,p,q)=px+qy+pq-z$. So, [Charpit's auxiliary equations](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~mate/misc/partial_diffeqs/charpits_method_compl_int.pdf) are given by: $$ds={dp \over 0}={dq \over 0}= {dz \over z+pq}={dx \over x+q}={dy \over y+p}$$ Now, from $$ds={dp \over 0}, ds={dq \over 0} \implies p=C, q=D $$ being arbitray constants. Now, I have to use $$dz=pdx+qdy=Cdx+Ddy$$ we get $$z(x,y)=Cx+Dy+E$$ Now, I am stuck, because we need to have some relationship between $C$ and $D$ to have only two independent constants

I think we should use Charpit's equations to get the relation.

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting the constants $p=C$ and $q=D$ into the original equation you already get
$$
z=Cx+Dy+CD
$$
so that $E=CD$.

Additionally, $(y+C)=A(x+D)$ so that also $z+CD=(C+DA)(x+D)$.

Comment: under $dz$ we have $p*F_p+q*F_q=p*(x+q)+q*(y+p)=px+pq+qy+pq=z+pq$ isn't it so?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, remark deleted.

Comment: @Lutz: Of course, obviously the linear solution $z=Cx+Dy+CD$ is a particular solution of the PDE. But what is the general solution of the PDE ?

Comment: The question was for the complete integral $z=f(x,y,a,b)$ or $0=g(x,y,z,a,b)$, that is, to find the characteristic curves and eliminate $p,q$ from their description. A solution requires further steps.